# Opening text files on codeblocks

Tags: c++, debugging, c++17, codeblocks

I try to debug by using `cerr` in c++. I know it's efficient for text editors like sublime.

But I wanted to know if there is a way i can open the output error text file on codeblocks in real time which would reflect the changes as soon as I run the program.

Right now when i do this, this happens:
[image: Reload notice.]

Is there any way to do this efficiently,so that the file gets updated withput giving prompt each time?

Comment: If you have the right tools installed, you want `tail -f <path to file>`. Unfortunately these tools don't come stock with windows. [Fortunately...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

Comment: Note: Code::Blocks has a GUI front-end for the GDB debugger and debuggers... They kick ass for seeing what's going on in a program and are usually more effective than real-time logging.

Comment: There are many log file viewers around which are more suited than editors for this. E.g they allow colouring of lines or words according to key words you set and allow filtering of messages you deem more important using regular expressions. My favourite at the moment is klogg. I also like LogExpert but it is too slow with gigabyte length log files.